# which way to write a api reference in gradle we should choose

Tags: gradle

Now in my project have many way to add dependency in `build.gradle`, it looks like not so clean so I want to choose one way in whole project, now the gradle version is 6.0,the dependency like this:

```
api "com.zaxxer:HikariCP:3.4.5"
```

or this:

```
api group: 'com.aliyun.oss', name: 'aliyun-sdk-oss', version: '3.8.0'
```

or this:

```
api "com.baomidou:mybatis-plus-boot-starter:3.2.0"
```

and this:

```
api("org.coody.framework:coody-elock:alpha-1.3.4")
```

and many other way. This make me confusing, what is the difference with ' and "? what is the differece with ( or not? which way is the recommand way? which way is the better way? and why we should write that way?

Answer (score 0):

These are all forms of **Dependency notations**. See the documentation here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html

It is confusing to see that there are many ways to do the same thing, but it is best to stick with one style and use throughout the project.

The most common form you'll see is these two:

```
api "com.baomidou:mybatis-plus-boot-starter:3.2.0" // double quoted string
api 'com.baomidou:mybatis-plus-boot-starter:3.2.0' // single quoted string
```

For the other questions, you need to know that there are (2) ways of writing the Gradle build file:

- Groovy DSL (`build.gradle` )
- Kotlin DSL (`build.gradle.kts`) - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html

As you can tell by the name, one using the Groovy language and one uses Kotlin.

> what is the difference with `'` and `"`

In the Groovy DSL, a single quoted string and double quoted string are effectively the same. There are differences are described in the documentation [here](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings), but for the above example the same result is achieved. It boils down to preference to which one you use.

In the Kotlin DSL, single quote denotes a [`Char`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char/) and a double quotes is a [`String`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/). So if you're using the Kotlin DSL `""` double quotes is a must.

> what is the differece with ( or not?

In the Groovy DSL, parenthesis are optional. This is a feature of the Groovy language itself and not something Gradle implemented. You can read more about it here: https://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_omitting_parentheses. In general, there is no difference, it boils down to preference.

Kotlin also has this feature as well, but since it is statically typed, there are restrictions on where it can and can not be used irrelevant of Gradle. You can ready more about it here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter

> which way is the better way? and why we should write that way?

There is no better or right way to do things. What matters is consistency. Stick to one style and use it throughout the project.

---

Aside, the Spring Boot team recently migrated to Gradle. You can read about their migration efforts in the blog here: https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/08/migrating-spring-boot-s-build-to-gradle

In the comments of the blog, it is explained why they chose the Groovy DSL over the Kotlin DSL: https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/08/migrating-spring-boot-s-build-to-gradle#comment-4946981443

> In our experience, using the Kotlin DSL requires some assistance from your IDE whereas the Groovy DSL can be written by hand. While the auto-completion for the Kotlin DSL is excellent in IntelliJ IDEA, that's not the case in Eclipse. Our team uses a mixture of Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA and we also want the project to be accessible to contributors no matter what IDE they use. All in all, that led to us using the Groovy DSL for our build.gradle scripts.